# NodeMCU Server not responding

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

Using NodeMCU to act as a wifi access point. The access point is working and I can connect to it, and when I visit 192.168.4.1, `print(payload)` my request is printed to the console so that's all working but Safari on iOS complaining that the server has stopped responding.

```
function initialConnection()
  wifi.setmode(wifi.SOFTAP)

    -- Setup as Access Point
    print(wifi.ap.config({
        ssid = "SSIDNAME",
        pwd = "SSIDPASSWORD",
        auth = wifi.OPEN
    }))

  server = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)

  if server then
    server:listen(80, function(conn)
      conn:on("receive",function(conn,payload)
        print(payload)
        conn:send("<h1> Hello, NodeMCU!!! </h1>")
      end)
    end)
  end

  -- statusLed:flashBlue( 100 )
end
```

This is the request which gets printed to the console

```
GET /?gddf HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.4.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.3.12 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14C92 Safari/602.1
Accept-Language: en-us
DNT: 1
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: Not sure if it makes any difference but in the second callback the socket parameter shouldn't be called `conn` as this "overlays" with the `conn` of the first callback. Make it something like `function(sck,payload) sck:send()`.

Comment: Out of curiosity I printed the [address of] the connection parameter at each level of nesting, i.e., print(conn) conn:on("sent", function(sck) print(sck) sck:close() end)end).  The address of the object passed as conn was the same as sck.  The only object that had a different address was the one passed to the disconnection callback, they didn't  match any of the values used anywhere else in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this:

```
srv = net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80, function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(sck, payload)
    print(payload)
    sck:send("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<h1>Hello, NodeMCU.</h1>")
end)
conn:on("sent", function(sck) sck:close() end)end)
```

Comment: Even though it's likely the correct answer (from our [GitHub start page](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/README.md#programming-model)) it's not a good answer because it doesn't explain _what_ was wrong or _why_ the original code doesn't work.

Comment: It does work thanks, I've up voted the answer, if you could add a brief explanation of why/what I was doing wrong I can accept it as the answer. Is it just the header stuff I was missing?

Comment: You weren't returning a valid response, according to the HTTP protocol.  One other note, if you ever need the response to be bigger than a single network frame, include the Connection: close header in the response.  Counting bytes for a Content-length header is often impractical, Connection: close tells the requesting host that the server's response is complete when it closes the connection.